# OCaml: Modify input typed data for a function

Tags: ocaml

I have a function "flat" who work in this way

```
let myList=[(0,1);(0,2);(0,3);(1,5);(2,4);(3,5);(5,4);(5,6);(4,3)];;

let flat  = List.fold_left (fun acc (x,y) -> x::y::acc) [] ;;

flat myList

- : int list = [4; 3; 5; 6; 5; 4; 3; 5; 2; 4; 1; 5; 0; 3; 0; 2; 0; 1]
```

I have a Typed data Graph defined in this way:

```
type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a ) list;;

let myList2= Gr[(0,1);(0,2);(0,3);(1,5);(2,4);(3,5);(5,4);(5,6);(4,3)];;
```

How modify the "flat" for this type?

**The result should be the same but the input has to be a Graph**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that :

```
  # type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a ) list;;
    type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a) list
    # let flat (Gr l)= List.fold_left (fun acc (x,y) -> x::y::acc) [] l;;
    val flat : 'a graph -> 'a list = <fun>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the list from graph type by simple match :

```
let Gr l = myList2 in 
       flat l;;
```